# MFC showing picture on controls doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm trying to show some images into my form. I've looked around a bit and tried some ways, but nothing works.
Here's my two attemps:

1. Added a picture control to my dialog;
2. Changed its type to Bitmap;
3. Added/drawed a bmp into resources;
4. In the picture control property changed Image to the id of my resource

In this way in the resource editor I can see the image correctly loaded but at run-time I don't see nothing.
Attempt 2:

```
CImage  imgImmagine;

switch( imgImmagine.Load( _T("img/forza.bmp") ) )
{
case S_OK:
    m_stForza.SetBitmap( (HBITMAP)imgImmagine );
    m_stForza.Invalidate();
    break;
case E_FAIL:
    AfxMessageBox( _T("Nessuna immagine trovata!") );
    break;
};
```

This time I obviously don't see anything in the dialog editor, but neither at runtime.
Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was (as usual) a Visual Studio 2010 problem, after some random operations the images now load correctly.